# Convert week numbers into dates

Tags: r

I have a table with several columns and one of them has always 6 digits where the first four represent the year and the last two the weeks of that year. I would need to convert this column into dates.

For instance:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10, 3, TRUE), Year_Week = c(201718, 201719, 201720 ) )
```

where the column Year_Week needs to be converted into Date type like Date_conv in df2

```
 dt2 <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10, 3, TRUE), Year_Week = c(201718, 201719, 201720 ), Date_conv = c("2017-05-01", "2017-05-08", "2017-05-15" ))
```

I use the UK convention.
I tried to convert the Year_Week column into string then use strsplit. Another approach was to use  parse_date_time. Unfortunately, I don't get it in the proper form but a completly wrong one. For instance,
parse_date_time(dt1$Year_Week, "YW")
convert everything into the 2017-11-03
Any help on this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in base R using `as.Date` but you also need to specify day of the week to get an exact day. Using 1st day of the week (Monday) as an arbitrary date.

```
as.Date(paste0(dt1$Year_Week, 1), '%Y%W%u')
#[1] "2017-05-01" "2017-05-08" "2017-05-15"
```

Read `?strptime` for various formats.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `ISOweek2date`

```
ISOweek::ISOweek2date(sub("^(....)(..)", "\\1-W\\2-1", dt1$Year_Week))
#[1] "2017-05-01" "2017-05-08" "2017-05-15"
```